# Code Generator for SDK

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have certain SDK and I want to write a code generator based on the user input. I have designed UI to get the inputs from the user. Is there any known design pattern for such task. Question that confusing me are

Where and how should i store the user inputs.
Should I store them in internal datastructure or some form of `xml` or `json` format so that it could be used again.

I am doing this as part of Visual Studio package and have written menu item for the same.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this cannot be answered generally. Where to store user input data depends on how much it is (Does it fit into the memory?) and whether you want to use it longer than the program runs (e.g. for logging or loading user input when running again).

Which design pattern(s) to use is rather dependent on what exactly you do with the user input than on the fact that it is user input. For example if you treat your generated code as an object and you will generate more than one of these objects, you could think of implementing a "Builder" design pattern to generate tis code object. If the generated code will have a generic structure which is just slightly altered by the user input, you can look at "Template Methods".